# How to order items in a Firebase array by timestamp using .orderby()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am attempting to enable my Vue.js app to retrieve items from Firestore database and arrange those items in order by timestamp. Normally, I would use:

```
let ref = db.collection('users').orderBy('timestamp')
```

... if the timestamp was simply a doc item. However, I have this app set so that `timestamp` is an object inside a firebase doc array item called `events`.

How can I set up the above statement to use the `timestamp` inside the `events` array doc item to arrange my items by the timestamps?

UPDATED FUNCTION

```
      let newDetails = this.newDetails
      let timestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('lll')
      let ref = db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
              doc.ref.update({'events': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                'name': doc.data().name,
                'details': newDetails,
                'timestamp': moment(Date.now()).format('lll')
              })
            })
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to order a query based on individual values in an array type document field. You will have to promote this timestamp value to its own field to perform ordering with it.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Perhaps I should expand a little. See the function which I added to the question above. In this function, objects are added to an array called ```events```. ```timestamp``` is also added as an object into the array. How can I reconfigure this function so that each new event maintains a timestamp, without the timestamp being added as an array object?

Comment: This question about updating a document sounds like a completely different question than the one you originally asked about ordering/querying documents.  If you have a question about how to write a document, please post it as a separate question so that others can benefit from having a clear problem and solution (questions that drag out over multiple problems are not very helpful for others).

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861186/how-to-assign-a-timestamp-to-an-array-type-doc-item-in-firebase