# How to assign a timestamp to an array type doc item in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am attempting to build a Vue.js app that enables dynamic pushing of items into an array in Cloud Firestore. The items are in the `events` array, contains various objects, one of which is a timestamp. See function below:

```
let newDetails = this.newDetails
let newImage = this.imageUrl
let timestamp = moment(Date.now()).format('lll')
let ref = db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
            doc.ref.update({
                'events': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                    'name': doc.data().name,
                    'details': newDetails,
                    'image': newImage,
                    'timestamp': moment(Date.now()).format('lll')
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

My goal is to render each array item to the DOM, based on the order of the timestamps. I initially tried setting up the following Vuex action (see below again) to use an `.orderBy()` function in order to achieve this goal:

```
setCurrentUser: async context => {
    let ref = db.collection('users').orderBy('events')
    let snapshot = await ref.where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
    const users = []
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let currentUserData = doc.data()
        currentUserData.id = doc.id
        users.push(currentUserData)
    })
    context.commit('setCurrentUser', users)
},
```

However, I understand that it might not be possible to order these items based on timestamps inside array type doc items. Any recommendations on how to assign a timestamp to each array item in Firestore without assigning timestamp as an array object, so that the array type doc items can still be arranged based on timestamp?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, here is the question re-phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the available data-types for Cloud Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

I would suggest using a `Map` to solve the problem of sorting the events based on the timestamp.

**Option 1:**  `Map<Timestamp, Event>`
The key can be Timestamp if there can be no events in the same time.
The reason for setting the key as `Timestamp` is because the `Map` is sorted by `Key` and then by `Value` by Cloud Firestore.

**Option 2:** If there can be more than one event for a user at the same time, the key can be `Event`. So the map would look something like this `Map<Event,Timestamp>` and you can sort based on the values after retrieving the `Map` from Firestore.

**Option 3:** If you can store all the events in another collection `Events`, then the `documentId` of event can be the key. So the `Map` would be `Map<String,Timestamp>`. I would suggest this option if a user can have a lot of events.

Hope this helps.